What's wrong with using the word "Credit" in a table header using spreadtab and siunitx?
Issue
When compiling the MWE below I get the following error:
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number 'ed'.
I don't know what it means and I cannot solve it.
HOWEVER, what I find very interesting, weird and frustrating, is that it seems to come from the word Credit that I use.
If I replace this word by Cost, I don't get the error.
If I replace this word by Credi, Cred or Cre, I still get a similar error, but no longer for Cr.
I noticed I can also add row{1} = {guard} below the colspec, it works without any of those errors. But I don't count that as a solution, rather as a work-around.
Question
What is going on here? Are any of the letters used in Credit protected in a spreadtab table or something?
And how do I fix it without the work-around? How can I just use the word Credit? I mean, maybe I want to use other words too which will also give me that error.
EDIT: New information
Regarding what I mentioned above about not being able to write Credit but I can write Cr; it appears that I can write every letter of the alphabet except the letters d and e. What's funny about those letters specifically in a siunitx column?
MWE
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{spreadtab}
\RequirePackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\NewTblrEnviron{book}
\SetTblrInner[book]{
    row{1} = {guard},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{book}{
    width = 0.4\linewidth,
    colspec = {
        X
        X[si = {
            table-format = 3.2,
            table-number-alignment = right,
        }]
    },
}}
@ Items & @ Credit \\
@ Item 1 & 1 \\
@ Item 2 & 2
\end{spreadtab}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Add row{1} = {guard},

Without the guard and without \multicolumn, enclosing the problematic part in {} will still work.

Why are you counting the specific feature to solve this problem (guard) as a workaround? It is the intended way (otherwise you can also add extra pair of curly braces) to solve your problem

@Mane32 Steven wants to set the guard option globally and not repeat it in every tabular. So the question is how to activate that after some specific colspec.

Well perhaps if he defines it's own environment but I see that more cumbersome that just using row{1} = {guard} or just the triple curly braces {{{Credit}}}

@UlrikeFischer hi again, and indeed I don't want to repeat this every time. Part of the question was why it works for other words e.g. "Cost" but not for "Credit". It gives me hope that there's another solution than specifing row{1} = {guard} in every table.

it doesn't work for Credit because of the e as that is part of a number (e.g. 10e4). When siunitx hits that it realize something is wrong as the following d doesn't fit. Try e.g. Cre4dit and look what happens. So as long as you avoid e, it could work.  But relying on parsing details  is wrong. Make a feature request for tabularray that it provides a mean to guard a row always.

Oh! That makes sense. Thanks for the help everyone!

You are setting row{1} = {guard} as a default option, but since you are defining your colspec after that, the setting gets overriden. If you add row{1}={guard} after colspec it should work.
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{spreadtab}
\RequirePackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\NewTblrEnviron{book}
\SetTblrInner[book]{
    row{1} = {guard}, % this gets overriden by colspec as is a early definition
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{spreadtab}{{book}{
                    width = 0.4\linewidth,
                    colspec = {
                        X
                        X[si = {
                            table-format = 3.2,
                            table-number-alignment = right,
                        }]
                    },
                    row{1} = {guard}, % This works
            }}
            @ Items & @ Credit \\
            @ Item 1 & 1 \\
            @ Item 2 & 2
        \end{spreadtab}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}


Alright, I hadn't realized that colspec overrides my early definition. Is there a way I can avoid it being overridden?

Maybe. Do you always use spreadtab with tabularray? Do you have a defined format for all your first rows?
